# Superposed nav-item right alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I need to right align all of my navbar elements, except for one that I want in the middle:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item float-xs-right">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Sign out</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item float-xs-right">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/application/settings">Configuration</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item float-xs-right">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/application/settings">admin@mysite.com</a>
       </li>
   <li class="nav-item float-xs-right">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The `Configuration` item is superposing the `Sign Out` item, as the image below:

[image: menu itens]

1) How to solve the superposing ?

2) What if I want a item (`About` for example), to stay in the middle of the menu (not in the right) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of yet, you can't center items in v4, but here's a solution:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-flex:after {
    content: none;
  }
}
.navbar-flex > *:last-child {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse navbar-flex">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline float-xs-right">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
```

- I added a custom class: `navbar-flex` to the navbar
- I removed the `:after` pseudo-element from `.navbar`
- limited this behavior to screens wider than `992px` - go lower, if you want *(768px), but test to see if your elements do fit on smaller screens
- this example uses the markup from v4 examples

There are now three elements in the navbar:

- logo: will stick to left side
- middle `.navbar-nav`: this gets centered between logo and contents of right-side container, keeping equal distance from each.
- right-side container (in this example, an `.inline-form`) can be safely replaced with another `.navbar-nav` (yours) and it will stick to the right.

For your specific case, replace the `.inline-form` element (last child of `.navbar`) with the `.navbar-nav` from your question (you should also remove the `float-xs-right` classes from its children); and move the child you want centered in the middle `.navbar-nav`

If you need the un-prefixed version of it, here it is:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .navbar-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-flex:after {
    content: none;
  }
}
.navbar-flex > *:last-child {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

If you want it "boxed", just drop it in a `.container`.

And, one more thing: why did you name your question "Superposed nav-item right alignment" instead of "How can I center a navbar item in Bootstrap v4?"

:: }<(((*> ::

Comment: Nicely answered. Thanks.